# How do I register a system wide mime filter?

Tags: delphi

I've given the Delphi components from bsalsa.com a try.  These include a mime filter so that I can have access to the HTML returned from a server before it reaches the browser.  However this demo only filters browser instances in the current app whereas I need to register a system-wide filter.

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see MSDN, [About Pluggable MIME filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#About_Pluggable_MIME):

> You must register a permanent
>   pluggable MIME filter in the registry
>   with the key
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PROTOCOLS\Filter\
>   and with a value set to the CLSID of
>   the pluggable MIME filter.